# How to add prometheus and grafana to spring boot

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, monitor

I have a spring boot project, and I want add prometheus to monitor it.
In application.properties, i have added

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus
```

and

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - prometheus
```

added in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml

```
  myapps:
    image: myimages:1.0.1        
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - myprojects
    container_name: myapps

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml     
    networks:
      - myprojects
    container_name: prometheus  
      
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"    
    networks:
      - myprojects
    depends_on:
      - prometheus 
    container_name: grafana  
     
networks:
  myprojects: {}
```

My prometheus.yml

```
 - job_name: 'myapps'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['myapps:9091']
```

But when I check *http://localhost:9090/targets*,
for *http://localhost:9091/actuator/prometheus* ,
it's state down and have message

**Get "http://localhost:9091/actuator/prometheus": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9091: connect: connection refused**

So how can i fixed it or i miss any configuration?